# Scraping data from clicked links on page then moving to next page & repeating in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, pagination, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm struggling to get a casperjs to move on to the next page after it has recursively worked through the links on the page.

I can get it to take data from each page and move through the pages, or click on each link on a page, but I can't get it doing both.

```
var utils = require('utils');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  waitTimeout: 10000,
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  }
});

var currentPage = 1;
var i = 0;
var links = [];
var link_titles = [];


var terminate = function() {
    this.echo("Exiting..").exit();
};

function getSelectedPage() {
    var el = document.querySelector('td.cur');
    return parseInt(el.textContent);
}

function getPageLinks () {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
  return [].map.call(links, function(link) {
    return link.getAttribute('href');
  });
}


function getLinkData(link) {
  this.thenOpen(link, function() {


    var title = this.getTitle();


    // Add the data from link
    var data = {
      title: title,
    };
    link_titles.push(data);

  });
}

function loopThroughLinks() {  

 if( i < links.length) {
    this.echo('[LINK #' + i + '] '+ links[i]);
    getLinkData.call(this, links[i]);
    i++;
    this.run(loopThroughLinks);

 }  else {
    utils.dump(link_titles);
    }       
}


function linkData(){
    links = this.evaluate(getPageLinks);
    this.run(loopThroughLinks);
}


var processPage = function() {  

    this.run(linkData);

    //PROBLEM EXISTS BELOW HERE - IF YOU COMMENT OUT FROM HERE IT RUNS AS EXPECTED FOR THE FIRST PAGE
    //WITH CODE BELOW INCLUDED, SKIPS this.run(linkData) AND JUST GOES THROUGH PAGES;
    this.then(function(){

    if (currentPage >= 3) {
        return terminate.call(casper);
    }

    currentPage++;

    this.echo("requesting next page: " + currentPage);
    this.capture("google-results-p" + currentPage + ".png");

    this.thenClick('a.pn span').then(function(){
        this.waitFor(function(){
            return currentPage === this.evaluate(getSelectedPage);

        }, processPage, terminate);
     }); 
  });   //COMMENT OUT TO HERE FOR WORKING ONE PAGE VERSION
}


casper.start('https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=casperjs');

casper.run(processPage);
```

Updated code to reflect multiple run calls.  Now looping through first page corrrectly, but printing results from first page for all other pages??

```
var utils = require('utils');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  waitTimeout: 10000,
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  }
});

var currentPage = 1;
var i = 0;
var links = [];
var link_titles = [];


var terminate = function() {
    this.echo("Exiting..").exit();
};

function getSelectedPage() {
    var el = document.querySelector('td.cur');
    return parseInt(el.textContent);
}

function getPageLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("h3.r a");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        try {
            // google handles redirects hrefs to some script of theirs
            return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1];
        } catch (err) {
            return e.getAttribute("href");
        }
    });
} 

function getLinkData(link) {
  this.thenOpen(link, function() {

    //var title = this.fetchText('title');
    var title = this.getTitle();


    // Add the staff data from link
    var data = {
      title: title,
    };
    link_titles.push(data);

    this.then(function(){  ///ADDED - BACK TO RIGHT PAGE FOR SELECTOR
    this.back();
    });

  });
}

function loopThroughLinks() {  

 if( i < links.length) {
    this.echo('[LINK #' + i + '] '+ links[i]);
    getLinkData.call(this, links[i]);
    i++;
    this.then(loopThroughLinks);

 }  else {
    utils.dump(link_titles);
    }       
}


function linkData(){
    links = this.evaluate(getPageLinks);
    this.then(loopThroughLinks);
}


var processPage = function() {  

    this.wait(2000, function(){
    this.then(linkData);
    });


    this.wait(2000, function(){
    this.then(function(){

    if (currentPage >= 3) {
        return terminate.call(casper);
    }


    this.echo("requesting next page: " + currentPage);
    this.capture("google-results-p" + currentPage + ".png");


    currentPage++;


    this.thenClick('a.pn span').then(function(){
        this.capture('google-results-2-p' + currentPage + '.png');
        this.waitFor(function(){
            return currentPage === this.evaluate(getSelectedPage);

        }, processPage, terminate);
     }); 
  });
 });
}


casper.start('https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=casperjs');

casper.then(processPage);

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have only one `casper.run()` (and only one `casper.start()`) call. `run()` starts the CasperJS step queue and will finish execution if there are no further steps. The only call that needs to stay is `casper.run(processPage);`, but all other `this.run(...)` calls need to be changed to `this.then(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response / help.  That makes sense.  Having done the above, if i leave casper.run(processPage) it does nothing, changing to casper.start(...), casper.then(processPage); casper.run(),  it's executing the first page, then echoing moving to next page but stopping.  Definitely moving in the right direction though!  I'll have a play about again, but if you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again for taking the time to answer. :)

Comment: It's now looping through the first pages links, then printing results from links, then looping through the pages and printing the results for page 1's links for every page!!! i.e. not looping through p2 links, p3 links etc.

Comment: They show that it is correctly moving through each page until the end, then teminating as you would expect it to.  I've tried the same code on several sites too.  It seems that when it moves to the next page and every page after that, it is going straight to utils.dump(link_titles) in the loopThroughLinks function, rather than evaluating the new links on the new page and actually looping through them, getting the data and dumping the new data!

Comment: Got it working.  Had to add i = 0 when at the utils.dump(link_titles) call so that I was reset to 0 for the other loops.  Thank you very much for your help in pointing me in the right direction. Teaching myself to code and have always tried not to ask questions so that I learn more. Had been stuck with that for a couple of days and couldn't find anything anywhere online, so great to know that there are helpful people like your good self out there. Much appreciated @Artjom B. Thank you.